# How to query an index in WHERE and ORDER BY clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-indexes

Please refer to this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html) of MySQL 8.0 new DESC index capability.

Let's say I have an index like this:

```
INDEX worstReviewIdx (rating ASC, hasReview DESC, id DESC)
```

This allows me to ORDER BY rating ASC, hasReview DESC, id DESC very quickly. However, in my use case I need to provide pagination. If I LIMIT a query by 10, I need to be able to find the next 10 items that maintain the aforementioned sorted order.

Does MySQL allow me to do something like this (where lastWorstReveiewIdx is the index of the last item in the previous pagination):

```
SELECT ... WHERE worstReviewIdx < {lastWorstReviewIdx} ORDER BY worstReviewIdx
```

Comment: Before 8.0 any index defined as descending was actually an ascending index read backwards. With 8.0 descending indexes are truly descending indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with ASC vs DESC, as much as it is with "remembering where you left off", *then* using an `ORDER BY` that matches the index to find the next 10.

In your case, "where you left off" is a triple `(rating, hasReview, id)` and using that to say essentially

```
WHERE (rating, hasReview, id) > ($r, $h, $id)   -- not quite right
ORDER BY rating ASC, hasReview DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

(I suggest using `LIMIT 11` so you can know whether there will be more.)

I am unclear as to whether MySQL 8.0 has optimized the "row constructor" expression as shown in the `WHERE`.  Anyway, it cannot go back and forth like you need with a mixture of ASC/DESC.  So, you will need to spell out a rather long complex boolean expression as discussed here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

You can avoid much of this discussion and complexity if you add a `GENERATED` column that is computed as `(- rating)` and then use it instead of `rating` -- this will let all three be `DESC`.  (And you won't need 8.0's new index feature.)